# Popularity of RowCallbackHandler with JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring

There are often times when I have need for a RowCallbackHandler, because in processing the result set I don't map each row to a single type, nor each result set to a single data structure. Instead, I may map the majority rows to a specific Java bean, and add the remainder to a list for post-processing.

In these cases, I need a callback with return type void, and the only callback which satisfies this is RowCallbackHandler.

But I don't come across many examples of this, and I have to admit, it's aesthetically nicer to use JDBC and loop through a ResultSet, than to use the clunky Spring callbacks. Is RowCallbackHandler more common than I think? I'm curious what people have to say...

---

**Edit**: Some people have asked for my data model. Okay, there's a `nodes` table and an `edges` table. If there's an edge between nodes A and B, that edge can signify two things:

1. A and B are disjoint nodes that interact
2. A is a member of B, or vice versa

In the second case, I need to add these group nodes to a list. They can't be mapped to a Java bean yet, because they don't signify interactions between disjoint nodes.

Perhaps what I should be doing, instead, is to have 2 queries, one that retrieves case (1), another that retrieves case (2). Case (1) could be mapped to a Java bean, case (2) to a List.

If this is indeed better, then maybe `RowCallbackHandler` is a bad code smell?

Comment: be interesting to see an example of code you're talking about? FWIW I tend to use Spring with Ibatis, so don't use callback row handler very much either...

Comment: I'm kind of curious what kind of data model you have that doesn't map fully to a java bean, where some column values are used for some other purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to process the whole result set, without returning anything, simply use a `ResultSetExtractor<Void>` (and one of the JdbcTemplate methods taking it as argument).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class that's composed of your bean objects(s), plus the list.  Then fill it in a ResultSetExtractor or RowCallbackHandler.  Then your return type can change from void to the new class' type.